# Prove that $x < y$ implies $x^{1/n} < y^{1/n}$.

Tags: proof-writing, solution-verification

Let $x$ and $y$ be positive real numbers and let $m$ and $n$ be positive integers.

Prove that $x < y$ implies $x^{1/n} < y^{1/n}$.

I have so far figured out two different approaches to prove this.

1. By induction:

Base case: $P(1)\iff x^{1/1} < y^{1/1} \iff x<y$

Inductive step: $P(n+1)\iff x^{1/n+1} < y^{1/n+1} $

But then I'm stuck from here as I 'm not sure on how to solve $1/n+1$.

2. Another approach is to use direct proof:

By rules of inequalities we know

$x<y\implies x-x < y-x$

$\implies xy < yy$

$\implies xx < xy$

Hence $x^{1/n} < y^{1/n}$
as
$(x^1)^{1/n} < (y^1)^{1/n}$

May I ask how can I solve for $1/n+1$ at the first approach and is the second approach correct at all?

Comment: There isn't any close connection between $x^{1/n}$ and $x^{1/(n+1)}$, so induction probably isn't the most natural approach.

Comment: You mention m and n at the beginning. But m is never used in the question. Did you write the question exactly? Just checking... maybe m is used in later parts after this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One can argue this way: Let if possible, there exists some $n$ such that $x^{\frac{1}{n}}\geqslant y^{\frac{1}{n}}$ then take nth power both sides and we get $x\geqslant y$. Everything is fine with inequality as $x$ and $y$ are positive.

Answer (score 2):

First we prove a simple property. Given $a,b,c,d$ are positive real numbers

(eqn 1)

$a \ge c$ and $b \ge d \implies ab \ge cd$

This is pretty trivial but isn't usually given as one of the standard inequality rules.

$\boldsymbol{Proof}$:

Given $a \ge c$ and $b \ge d$

Since $a \ge c$, we know that $ad \ge cd$

Since $b \ge d$, we know that $ab \ge ad$

So by transitivity we know that $ab \ge cd$

$\boldsymbol{Induction}$:

Now we can use induction to prove that given e and f are positive real numbers

(eqn 2)

$e \ge f \implies e^n \ge f^n$

(eqn 3)

Given $e \ge f$

Base case, n=1 is trivial:

Since $e \ge f$

$e^1 \ge f^1$

So true for n=1.

Assume true for $n=k$

(eqn 4)

$e^k \ge f^k$

Now we prove it's true for $n=k+1$

Using (3) and (4) and rule (1), we know that

$e^k(e) \ge f^k(f)$

$e^{k+1} \ge f^{k+1}$

That completes our proof of eqn 2.

$\boldsymbol{Substitution}$:

Now we can substitute $e = x^{1/n}$ and $f= y^{1/n}$ into eqn 2, where x and y are positive real numbers. Since x and y are positive, e and f are positive (we are taking the positive principal nth root).

$x^{1/n} \ge y^{1/n} \implies (x^{1/n})^n \ge (y^{1/n})^n$

$x^{1/n} \ge y^{1/n} \implies x \ge y$

Now we can take the contrapositive:

$x < y \implies x^{1/n} < y^{1/n}$

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

$$x^{\frac{1}{n}}>y^{\frac{1}{n}}$$
What happens if we raise everything to the power of
$$\frac{n}{n+1}\;\;?$$