# If $\;0<a<b\;,\;$ then $\;a^{1/n} < b^{1/n}$

Tags: real-analysis

I am supposed to prove $\;a^{1/n}<b^{1/n}\;$ for $\;0<a<b\;$ and $\;n\in\mathbb N\,.$

I tried using induction but it didn't work out.

For $\;n=1:$
$$a^{1/1} < b^{1/1}\iff a<b$$

For $\;n+1:$

$a^{1/(n+1)}=a^{1/n}\cdot a^{1/(n(n+1))}<b^{1/n}\cdot b^{1/(n(n+1))}>b^{1/n}\cdot b^{1/(n(n+1))}=b^{1/(n+1)}$

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3887296/42969